# Java Script/Vue.Js group by an object base on name

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to group by an object based on partial name and add them into variables

```
data =
{
   SCHOOL-ADMISSION_YEAR: "2021"
   SCHOOL-SCHOOL_NAME: "ABC SCHOOL"
   SCHOOL-SCHOOL_LOCATION: "NEWYORK"
   ENROLLMENT-ADMISSION_YEAR: "2021"
   ENROLLMENT-SUBMISSION_DATE: "2020-04-02"
   ENROLLMENT-ENROLLMENT_DATE: "2020-06-02"
}
```

The group should be

```
 School =
  {
   ADMISSION_YEAR: "2021",
   SCHOOL_NAME: "ABC SCHOOL",
   SCHOOL_LOCATION: "NEWYORK",
  }

 Enrollment =
  {
   ADMISSION_YEAR: "2021",
   SUBMISSION_DATE: "2020-04-02",
   ENROLLMENT_DATE: "2020-06-02",
  }

var school = data.filter(p => p.contains('SCHOOL'));
var enrollment = data.filter(p => p.contains('ENROLLMENT'));
```

Comment: Nothing that is shown is specific to Vue. It's JS.

Comment: Thank you.I will update the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain objects don't have `filter` method and need to be iterated with a loop. In order to be filtered and mapped, an object can be converted to entry array and back, e.g with ES2019 `fromEntries`:

```
const school = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(data)
  .filter(([key]) => key.includes('SCHOOL-'))
  .map(([key, val]) => [key.replace('SCHOOL-', ''), val])
);
```

For an array of objects it's:

```
const school = Object.entries(data)
  .filter(([key]) => key.includes('SCHOOL-'))
  .map(([key, val]) => ({ [key.replace('SCHOOL-', '')]: val }));
```

Comment: I have one more question if you don't mind.Instead of creating single object ,can i create an array of objects.Each key value will be an object inside an array.

Comment: What exactly should the resulting array look like?

Comment: [
{ADMISSION_YEAR: "2021"},
{SCHOOL_NAME: "ABC SCHOOL"},
{SCHOOL_LOCATION: "NEWYORK"}
]

Comment: Updated. Generally an array of objects with one key is not very practical, ES6 Map may be more suitable as iterable collection of key value pairs. And in Vue an object is easily iterable in v-for as well.

Comment: Thank you very much.working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you:

```js
function getAllWithSubstring(substring) {
  let dataWithSubstring = [];

  for (let key of Object.keys(data)) {
    if (key.includes(substring)) {
      dataWithSubstring.push(data[key])
    }
  }
  return dataWithSubstring;
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```js
getAllWithSubstring("SCHOOL"); // => ['2021', 'ABC SCHOOL', 'NEWYORK']
getAllWithSubstring("ENROLLMENT"); // => ['2021', '2020-04-02', '2020-06-02']
```